# PrimeFaces DataTable manual selection

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am working with PrimeFaces 3.5 and I have problem with validation with some fields in datatable.

I create example depends on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf and @FaceValidation for my fields. But because @FaceValidation in JSF 2.0 doesn't support EJB yet I decide to validation in onEdit function (in my bean).

And here si problem.

How to manual selection some row to get in edit mode (just like if I clicked pencil) in bean in function onEdit(RowEditEvent event) if a get error (like "Username is already taken", etc)?
Just like if I have @FaceValidation and throw exception.

I hope I was clear :)

Thanks in advance.
Domen

Comment: Or in other word how to focused row after editing it if get an own error (min length error, etc)

Comment: My solution after 2 days of searching: In function onEdit(RowEditEvent) when we get exception we call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed()